# Proper CSS syntax to get json encoded data attributes by jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I need to fetch one of json encoded data inside data-people:

```
<ul>
  <li data-test="one" data-people='{"name" : "Paul", "color" : "black"}'>Paul</li>
  <li data-test="two" data-people='{"name" : "John", "color" : "blond"}'>John</li>
  <li data-test="three" data-people='{"name" : "Jane", "color" : "black"}'>Jane</li>
</ul>
```

It is pretty straight forward to fetch via data-test (just example):

```
$('ul li[data-test="two"]').show();
```

Now I want to show ul li with data-people that has color blond (ignoring data-test that only exist for sample above).

I tested below but this doesn't work as expected:

```
$('ul li[data-people="{"color": "blond"}"]').show();
```

I don't mean to get color value like: `$('ul li').data('people').color`, but to *do* proper CSS syntax inside the object.

Any hint is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this in any clean way using just selectors except by using the `*=` ("attribute contains") selector. And that one will only work if the JSON contains *exactly* that substring - remove the space before `:` and it will stop working.

```
$('ul li[data-people*=\'"color" : "blond"\']').show();
```

What you probably *really* want is `.filter()`:

```
$('ul li[data-people]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('people').color == 'blond';
}).show();
```

This way you use the (fast) CSS selector engine to get only relevant elements (those that have a `data-people` attribute) and then filter the resultset using the callback function.

Comment: Hmmm, sounds reasonable. Is this definitive? So I can mark yours as a reply. Thanks

Comment: Notice this is not CSS syntax, these are jQuery selector syntaxes

Comment: And the question is tagged with [tag:jquery] ;)

Comment: I'm talking about the title ;)

Comment: Actually the first example works with just CSS, too: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/7f3HK/

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I thought I said at the end clearly: "but to do proper CSS syntax inside the object."